# Is C++ std::vector slower than C99 variable length arrays?

Tags: c++

I've seen some discussion about this. Many say that they should be the same speed. 
But I did some test myself. It seems to me code with std::vector is slower than code with array. But I don't quite understand why.. I used the following simple code.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/ptime.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/microsec_time_clock.hpp>

class TestTimer
{
public:
  TestTimer(const std::string & name) : name(name),
    start(boost::date_time::microsec_clock<boost::posix_time::ptime>::local_time())
  {}

  ~TestTimer()
  {
    using namespace std;
    using namespace boost;

    posix_time::ptime now(date_time::microsec_clock<posix_time::ptime>::local_time());
    posix_time::time_duration d = now - start;
    cout << name << " completed in " << d.total_milliseconds() / 1000.0 <<
            " seconds" << endl;
  }

private:
  std::string name;
  boost::posix_time::ptime start;
};


using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  // timing for vector calculations
  {
    int n = 100000;
    std::vector<double> a(n),b(n),c(n);

    double* aa = &a[0];
    double* bb = &b[0];
    double* cc = &c[0];

    TestTimer t("vector");
    for ( long int j = 0; j < 1000; j ++ )
    for ( int i = 0; i < n; i ++ )
      aa[i]=bb[i]*cc[i];
  }

  // timing for array calculations
  {
    int n = 100000;
    double a[n],b[n],c[n];

    double* aa = &a[0];
    double* bb = &b[0];
    double* cc = &c[0];

    TestTimer t("array");
    for ( long int j = 0; j < 1000; j ++ )
    for ( int i = 0; i < n; i ++ )
      aa[i]=bb[i]*cc[i];
  }

}
```

And I compiled and run the code with icpc using -O0 or -O3 (g++ gives very similar results. I repeated several times and the results are the same.):

```
icpc test.C -o test.x -O3 -Fa -g
./test.x
vector completed in 0.06 seconds
array completed in 0.03 seconds


icpc test.C -o test.x -O0 -Fa -g
./test.x
vector completed in 0.269 seconds
array completed in 0.279 seconds
```

It looks like with -O3, using array calculation is 2X faster than using the vector. I looked at the assembly code (for the part in the loop). For the assembly code compiled with -O0, they looks the same for vector and array. But when compiled with -O3, they look quite different. (see below)
I kinda understand the code is trying to move data from memory to register (with movapsx), do the multiplications (mulpdx) and move data back (moapsx). But What is the different between movsdq, movhpdq and movapsx and why do the compiler produce different code for array and vector?

assembly code (loop part) with -O3 using vectors:

```
movsdq  (%rbx,%r13,8), %xmm0
movsdq  0x10(%rbx,%r13,8), %xmm1
movsdq  0x20(%rbx,%r13,8), %xmm2
movsdq  0x30(%rbx,%r13,8), %xmm3
movhpdq  0x8(%rbx,%r13,8), %xmm0
movhpdq  0x18(%rbx,%r13,8), %xmm1
movhpdq  0x28(%rbx,%r13,8), %xmm2
movhpdq  0x38(%rbx,%r13,8), %xmm3
mulpdx  (%r9,%r13,8), %xmm0
mulpdx  0x10(%r9,%r13,8), %xmm1
mulpdx  0x20(%r9,%r13,8), %xmm2
mulpdx  0x30(%r9,%r13,8), %xmm3
movapsx  %xmm0, (%r15,%r13,8)
movapsx  %xmm1, 0x10(%r15,%r13,8)
movapsx  %xmm2, 0x20(%r15,%r13,8)
movapsx  %xmm3, 0x30(%r15,%r13,8)
```

assembly code (loop part) with -O3 using arrays:

```
movapsx  (%rbx,%rcx,8), %xmm0
movapsx  0x10(%rbx,%rcx,8), %xmm1
movapsx  0x20(%rbx,%rcx,8), %xmm2
movapsx  0x30(%rbx,%rcx,8), %xmm3
mulpdx  (%rsi,%rcx,8), %xmm0
mulpdx  0x10(%rsi,%rcx,8), %xmm1
mulpdx  0x20(%rsi,%rcx,8), %xmm2
mulpdx  0x30(%rsi,%rcx,8), %xmm3
movapsx  %xmm0, (%r13,%rcx,8)
movapsx  %xmm1, 0x10(%r13,%rcx,8)
movapsx  %xmm2, 0x20(%r13,%rcx,8)
movapsx  %xmm3, 0x30(%r13,%rcx,8)
```

**EDIT:**
I have update the code to test more cases:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/ptime.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/microsec_time_clock.hpp>

class TestTimer
{
public:
  TestTimer(const std::string & name) : name(name),
    start(boost::date_time::microsec_clock<boost::posix_time::ptime>::local_time())
  {}

  ~TestTimer()
  {
    using namespace std;
    using namespace boost;

    posix_time::ptime now(date_time::microsec_clock<posix_time::ptime>::local_time());
    posix_time::time_duration d = now - start;
    cout << name << " completed in " << d.total_milliseconds() / 1000.0 <<
            " seconds" << endl;
  }

private:
  std::string name;
  boost::posix_time::ptime start;
};


using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

  int n = 100;
  int N = 10000000;

  // timing for vector calculations
  {
    std::vector<double> a(n),b(n),c(n);

    double* aa = &a[0];
    double* bb = &b[0];
    double* cc = &c[0];

    {
    TestTimer t("vector1");
    for ( long int j = 0; j < N; j ++ )
    for ( int i = 0; i < n; i ++ )
      aa[i]=bb[i]*cc[i];
    }
  }

  // timing for vector calculations
  {
    std::vector<double> a(n),b(n),c(n);

    double* aa = &a[0];
    double* bb = &b[0];
    double* cc = &c[0];

    {
    TestTimer t("vector2");
    for ( long int j = 0; j < N; j ++ )
    for ( int i = 0; i < n; i ++ )
      a[i]=b[i]*c[i];
    }
  }

  // timing for array calculations
  {
    double a[n],b[n],c[n];

    double* aa = &a[0];
    double* bb = &b[0];
    double* cc = &c[0];

    {
    TestTimer t("array");
    for ( long int j = 0; j < N; j ++ )
    for ( int i = 0; i < n; i ++ )
      aa[i]=bb[i]*cc[i];  
    }
  }

  // timing for malloc calculations
  {
    double *a,*b,*c;

    a=(double*)malloc(sizeof(double)*n);
    b=(double*)malloc(sizeof(double)*n);
    c=(double*)malloc(sizeof(double)*n);

    double* aa = &a[0];
    double* bb = &b[0];
    double* cc = &c[0];

    {
    TestTimer t("malloc");
    for ( long int j = 0; j < N; j ++ )
    for ( int i = 0; i < n; i ++ )
      aa[i]=bb[i]*cc[i];
    }
  }

  // timing for new pointer calculations
  {
    double *a,*b,*c;

    a=new double[n];
    b=new double[n];
    c=new double[n];

    double* aa = &a[0];
    double* bb = &b[0];
    double* cc = &c[0];

    {
    TestTimer t("new pointer");
    for ( long int j = 0; j < N; j ++ )
    for ( int i = 0; i < n; i ++ )
      aa[i]=bb[i]*cc[i];
    }
  }

}
```

for n=100, N=10000000 I get:

```
g++ test.C -o test.x -O3 -Fa -g 
./test.x
vector1 completed in 0.487 seconds
vector2 completed in 0.504 seconds
array completed in 1.624 seconds
malloc completed in 0.409 seconds
new pointer completed in 0.502 seconds

icpc test.C -o test.x -O3 -Fa -g 
./test.x
vector1 completed in 0.318 seconds
vector2 completed in 0.319 seconds
array completed in 0.216 seconds
malloc completed in 0.295 seconds
new pointer completed in 0.289 seconds
```

for n=100000, N=10000, I get:

```
g++ test.C -o test.x -O3 -Fa -g 
./test.x
vector1 completed in 0.699 seconds
vector2 completed in 0.648 seconds
array completed in 0.397 seconds
malloc completed in 0.428 seconds
new pointer completed in 0.464 seconds

icpc test.C -o test.x -O3 -Fa -g 
./test.x
vector1 completed in 0.632 seconds
vector2 completed in 0.616 seconds
array completed in 0.308 seconds
malloc completed in 0.357 seconds
new pointer completed in 0.322 seconds
```

Comment: It's like comparing apples with bananas :-P ...

Comment: Your arrays are not legal C++.

Comment: In both cases your loop is dereferencing a `double*` so the work being done looks identical.

Comment: maybe I didn't say it clearly. I want to test the speed for the calculation in the for loop. And they are indeed different in my test. Anyone can explain?

Comment: @Andy: The downvotes should be a lesson: The C++ fanatics at this site do **not** like questions that even appear to denigrate the language. C99 VLAs are faster with regard to allocation and deallocation. That speedup doesn't matter if allocation/deallocation is rare compared to element access. That speedup also doesn't matter if VLA allocation fails. Vectors are allocated on the heap but VLAs on the are allocated on the stack, which is limited compared to the heap. That speedup also doesn't matter if you need the size extensibility of a vector. Variable length arrays are of a fixed size.

Comment: @DavidHammen Thanks. I know all the advantages of vector over array. But here I only care about performance. Are you saying the speed up is because VLA is on the stack and vector is on the heap?

Comment: That's the primary source of the speedup. Array element access/update will dominate over allocation/deallocation if N is large, and if N is large you most definitely do not want to allocate all that memory on the stack. Allocation/deallocation might dominate when N is small, and in that case allocating on the stack might not kill you.

Comment: Hmm, with gcc I get the exact same assembly for the vector case (adding {} so there is no doubt about deallocation being involved) and the array case, and the first still takes twice as long... Allocating on the heap with calloc also gives a fast loop. Not sure what makes the vector case slower.

Comment: @MarcGlisse I have the same observation.

Comment: If you memset(X,0,8*n) the 3 arrays before the loop, it makes the loop as slow as in the vector case.

Comment: @DavidHammen You are right. calculations with arrays with size of 100 is a much slower than vectors.

Comment: @MarcGlisse I found the same thing. But it is weird that the assembly code are the same after I add memset.

Answer (score 3):

You're not measuring **anything** to do with `std::vector` <strike>except the time taken to run their destructors and deallocate memory, which doesn't need to be done for the arrays.</strike>

<strike>Try putting the timer in a new scope, so it stops timing before you destroy the vectors, and you should see very similar times:</strike>

```
{
  TestTimer t("vector");
  for ( long int j = 0; j < 1000; j ++ )
  for ( int i = 0; i < n; i ++ )
    aa[i]=bb[i]*cc[i];
}
```

The reason is that a `std::vector` just has an array inside it, so by taking the address of the first element and performing all your calculations on that array you are not doing anything with the vector. Totally pointless test.

If you tested `a[i] = b[i] * c[i]` *that* would show if there's a difference when using a vector.

The small differences in object code may be due to the fact that the compiler isn't smart enough to tell that `&a[0]` and `&b[0]` and `&c[0]` don't alias each other when those addresses come from the vector's start pointer, whereas it can tell that for the arrays declared on the stack.

Comment: Wouldn't `TestTimer` be destroyed before the three vectors since it's declared last?

Comment: The timer is destroyed after the loops. So it measures the timing of the loops. That is the part I want to test..

Comment: I added the scope you mentioned and the timing is not changed. Using a[i] instead of aa[i] does not affect the timing as well.

Comment: @JonathanWakely At first I had the same reaction as you, but with gcc I get the same asm for the 2 loops and one takes twice as long to run, it is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of your measuring being pointless, one can answer your question with: "Yes, but it does not matter, and it doesn't compare anyway".

`vector` is indeed "slower" most of the time, but it hardly matters and the reason is because `vector` and a C-style array are entirely different things that do different things.

An array is allocated once and keeps that same size forever (until you free it). That allocation can happen on the stack (but needs not). `vector` on the other hand *necessarily* has to allocate its storage on the heap, which is not a free operation (and especially freeing memory is rather costly as compared to being automatic when allocated on the stack -- where it comes for free in the usual case and costs one register increment in the worst case).
There is no additional "smartness" built into an array. No safety net. Push more elements than will fit, and you have UB.

`vector` manages the storage for the elements within **and** offers variable size **and** reallocates and copies elements as needed when you push more elements, all transparently without you even knowing that it happens. None of that is possible at all with a C-style array unless you either cheat and over-allocate or you implement the same work that `vector` is doing for you behind the curtain. At which point your array becomes just as slow as `vector` (and most probably slower, unless you are a very experienced programmer).
Insofar, comparing the two is not at all possible in a meaningful way, they do totally different things. Only by coincidence (well, not so much by coincidence, really... but you get me), you can store objects in both of them and access them with `operator[]`.

Allocations/reallocations happen rarely (and are amortized, and can be avoided with proper use of `reserve` in most cases), so although they do make `vector` "slower", they hardly matter for the overall performance in the normal case. It only really matters if you allocate and free thousands of `vector`s and/or if you use `vector` in a terribly wrong way.

The "99.9% important" parts, such as e.g. accessing a random element at a given index are *exactly* the same speed for `vector` as for a C-style array. Except of course, in a debug build where most `vector` implementations do additional bounds-checking. But this, again, is useful extra functionality which of course you have to pay for. In a release build, the overhead is gone.

Comment: I am aware of all the security advantages of vector. But that does not explain the different assembly code they produce.

Comment: It is hard, if possible at all, to tell why that happens (and you can't even trivially be sure that the "obviously slower" version with more instructions _really_ runs slower). The difference in the assembly is moving doublewords versus quadwords into SSE registers which may be due to an auto-vectorizer or optimizer artefact, or for some other completely unrelated reason (scheduling or whatever, you name it). Change one compiler flag or move the code around in a real program, and it may look completely different again. You cannot make a valid conclusion from that.

Comment: Thing is, millions of people have used (and benchmarked!) `vector`, and while it certainly must be "slower" at least in some cases due to allocations and due to the extra stuff that it does for you, in practice the important operations turn out exactly as fast as if you used a raw array. Only you can do more stuff, and the stuff you do is safer and the code is cleaner.

Comment: OK. Thanks. I know all these might not be relevant in the end. But I was just curious.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your machine is about 100x faster than my AMD Phenom II, I suspect your optimised code has completely eliminated both loops. clang++ (3.6 from a couple of weeks ago) that I'm using does that for the VLA, but not for the vector, for some reason. Not entirely sure why.

If I add code to actually USE the calculated values in `aa`, then the result is nearly identical in optimised compile (and measuring performance of non-optimised code when using C++ vector is incorrect, unless you actually intend to deliver your production code with no optimisation!). With optimisation (-O3), the result is near enough identical:

```
vector completed in 0.286 seconds
x = 9.99985e+14
array completed in 0.284 seconds
x = 9.99985e+14
```

I ran it several times, and the second (array) variant is always 1-3 milliseconds faster, so about 1% of the total time.

This is my code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/ptime.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/microsec_time_clock.hpp>

class TestTimer
{
public:
  TestTimer(const std::string & name) : name(name),
    start(boost::date_time::microsec_clock<boost::posix_time::ptime>::local_time())
  {}

  ~TestTimer()
  {
    using namespace std;
    using namespace boost;

    posix_time::ptime now(date_time::microsec_clock<posix_time::ptime>::local_time());
    posix_time::time_duration d = now - start;
    cout << name << " completed in " << d.total_milliseconds() / 1000.0 <<
            " seconds" << endl;
  }

private:
  std::string name;
  boost::posix_time::ptime start;
};

using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  double x = 0;
  // timing for vector calculations
  {
    int n = 100000;
    std::vector<double> a(n),b(n),c(n);

    double* aa = &a[0];
    double* bb = &b[0];
    double* cc = &c[0];

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
    bb[i] = i * 2;
    cc[i] = i * 1.5;
    }

    TestTimer t("vector");
    for ( long int j = 0; j < 1000; j ++ )
    for ( int i = 0; i < n; i ++ )
        aa[i]=bb[i]*cc[i];

    for(auto v : a)
    {
    x += v;
    }
  }
  cout << "x = " << x << endl;

  // timing for array calculations
  {
    int n = 100000;
    double a[n],b[n],c[n];

    double* aa = &a[0];
    double* bb = &b[0];
    double* cc = &c[0];

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
    bb[i] = i * 2;
    cc[i] = i * 1.5;
    }

    TestTimer t("array");
    for ( long int j = 0; j < 1000; j ++ )
    for ( int i = 0; i < n; i ++ )
        aa[i]=bb[i]*cc[i];

    x = 0;
    for(auto v : a)
    {
    x += v;
    }
  }
  cout << "x = " << x << endl;

}
```

Comment: It seems my CPU is faster. You code runs for 0.061 seconds. And probably because I use intel compiler and intel CPU.